# Make appending dataframes (with unknown nrow) more efficient

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I am currently working on a function that enables me to do the following:

I have a list with csv-files which represent my datasets (around 800). I now want to iterate over that list, open each dataset and copy just 1 column (variable) and only append this column to a `data.table`. In the end, the `data.table` should have two columns, like this:

```
     ID    Value
     1     x
     1     y
     ..    .. 
     2     z
     2     a
     ..    ..
     n     ..
```

I have a working working function for that (see code below) but it seems very slow. I have read for example, that it is more efficient and faster to initialize the `data.table` in the beginning with its size so that the memory is already allocated because R seems to handle reallocation of memory not so well. I have read this [here](http://menugget.blogspot.nl/2011/11/another-aspect-of-speeding-up-loops-in.html#more), for example.

This is where I need your help - I can't say how big the table will be in the end since every dataset has a different size. Is there still a way to make my code more efficient?

```
read.var_overall <- function(applog_list, varname) {
  final_dt <- data.table(SN = "", Values = "") # initialization of the data.table 
                                               # but I don't know its size yet!

  for (i in 1:length(applog_list)) { # Iteration over the csv-list.
    if (app_log.isokay(as.character(applog_list[i]))) { # check if csv's format is okay
  values <- read.app_log(as.character(applog_list[i]))[, get(varname)] # read out the values
  sn <- read.sn(applog_list[i]) # get the ID

  dt <- data.table(SN = sn, Values = values) # create data.table for this dataset (csv)

  final_dt <- rbindlist(list(final_dt, dt)) # append datatables
     }
return(final_dt)
}
```

Comment: Seriously, learn to use `lapply` instead of a `for` loop. Then you'd get a list of data.tables, which you can combine with one call to `rbindlist`. Repeat with me: "Growing an object in a loop lands us in the [Second Circle of the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)."

Comment: I tried using ```lapply```. But since I am calling more than one function on each element of the list (```app_log.isokay```, ```read.app_log```, ```read.sn```) I thought it would not be possible with the ```apply``` functions. Plus I only want to apply the function when the if statement is true.